# How to create a UIScrollView in storyboard?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton

Using `storyboard` I created a `UIScrollView` and added a `UIImage` to `UIScrollview` and I want to  scroll the image in `storyboard`.

I tried but it will not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

show your code then only we can say anything but may be not need to set the content size of your scroll view then that scroll will work.